# How to see the actual error on Image "onerror" event?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have an image that is loaded using base64 however for some reason the image isn't loading so I can show a temp image, but need to know exactly why the image isn't loading. How can capture the actual error?

```
<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:'+image.mimeType+';base64, '+ image.frontImage)"
            onerror="getError($event)" />
```

in my getError nothing happens. I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: getError is not defined

```
 getError(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `(error)="getError($event)"`? Angular may be patching the img component....

Comment: try changing onerror to onError

Comment: security wise, you should be very careful when using bypassSecurityTrustUrl. this could lead to a potential XSS attack. you should use it ONLY if you are 100% sure that this is not a user input.

Comment: @julianobrasil so the method does get hit with (error) however therr still is no error. $event shows the entire list of html events.

Comment: You should see the error. I've built [a simple example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lswhk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Just open the devtools console (it's too summarized on stackblitz console).

Comment: @julianobrasil so with that stackblitz you are correct it writes the event to the console but if you expand it there isn't any detail to the error

Comment: As I said, "open the devtools console" (the stackblitz embedded console it's way too summarized). See the error on the regular chrome devtools.